# How to get the thumnail of a PDF uploaded on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am able to upload a file to Google Drive using the Google SDK. But the response that I receive does not contain a "thumbnailLink" field.

I would like to display a preview image for each file uploaded through my application. How can i go about it?

Here is my request code :

```
File driveFile = new File();
driveFile.setTitle("File Title");
driveFile.setMimeType(userFile.getContentType());

FileContent driveFileContent = new FileContent(userFile.getContentType(), userFile.asFile());                
File insertedDriveFile = driveService.files().insert(driveFile, driveFileContent).setConvert(true).execute();
```

and here is my response :

```
{
    "alternateLink" : "https://docs.google.com/file/d/...",
    "createdDate" : {
        "dateOnly" : false,
        "tzShift" : 0,
        "value" : 1345031115877
    },
    "description" : "Some Text",
    "downloadUrl" : "...",
    "editable" : true,
    "etag" : "\"qZporUffWgr4KlPui79y_IN18w8/MTM0NTAzMTExNjI1OA\"",
    "fileExtension" : "",
    "fileSize" : 15666,
    "id" : "0B4FbUv8OusD1Q3V2aFM2M2pVaEk",
    "kind" : "drive#file",
    "labels" : { "hidden" : false,
        "restricted" : false,
        "starred" : false,
        "trashed" : false,
        "viewed" : true
     },
    "lastModifyingUserName" : "Regis Bamba",
    "lastViewedByMeDate" : { "dateOnly" : false,
    "tzShift" : 0,
    "value" : 1345031115769
  },
    "md5Checksum" : "0baac1165bd1a004fa52eb9777e455df",
    "mimeType" : "application/pdf",
    "modifiedByMeDate" : { "dateOnly" : false,
        "tzShift" : 0,
        "value" : 1345031116258
      },
    "modifiedDate" : { "dateOnly" : false,
        "tzShift" : 0,
        "value" : 1345031116258
      },
    "originalFilename" : "Test File",
    "ownerNames" : [ "Regis" ],
    "parents" : [ { "id" : "0AIFbUv8OusD1Uk9PVA",
          "isRoot" : true,
          "kind" : "drive#parentReference",
          "parentLink" : "...",
    "selfLink" : "..."
  } ],
  "quotaBytesUsed" : 15666,
  "selfLink" : "...",
  "title" : "Test File",
  "userPermission" : { "etag" : "\"qZporUffWgr4KlPui79y_IN18w8/S0oJPFvxJQWU-e8QPUGRAAa4JaA\"",
  "id" : "me",
  "kind" : "drive#permission",
  "role" : "owner",
  "selfLink" : "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B4FbUv8OusD1Q3V2aFM2M2pVaEk/permissions/me",
  "type" : "user"
},
  "webContentLink" : "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B4FbUv8OusD1Q3V2aFM2M2pVaEk&export=download",
  "writersCanShare" : true
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your request and response? I just tried with OAuth Playground and the thumbnail was returned for pdfs.

Comment: Hi Claudio, I just tried too with the OAuth Playground and a PDF and it does NOT return the thumbnail neither. But I will update the question with my request and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thumbnail creation process is asynchronous so the `thumbnailLink` field is not included in the metadata returned by the file upload call. Try retrieving the same document after a small wait and it should include that field.